# Cannot run "npm start", shows missing shell files error. How to solve?

Tags: reactjs, windows, shell

I keep getting an error message every time I run "npm start" in windows. It always states that I am missing random shell files.

```
PS C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\GodKingFast-React> npm start

> godking-za@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

/bin/bash: /C/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/start-9992093e.sh: No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\GodKingFast-React> npm start

> godking-za@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

/bin/bash: /C/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/start-e7782f0f.sh: No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\GodKingFast-React>
```

It keeps saying that I am missing different shell files everytime I run "npm start". I am not sure how to fix this